# Mongoengine check if entire case insensitive string is contained in ListField()

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine, listfield

I am trying to build a query which returns all the objects that have a certain email address in their `ListField(EmailField())`.

I tried with mongoengine by executing

```
User.Objects.filter(emaillist__contains=email)
```

The problem is when the emailstring is a substring of an email contained in emaillist, the object is returned as well. However I only want it to be returned when the entire case insensitive emailstring is contained in the Listfield.

Is this possible somehow or by executing a raw query?
Any hints or help is much appreciated!

Jonas

Comment: Did you try the simplest approach as shown in this [link](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#searching-our-posts-by-tag)? Just querying by emaillist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#searching-our-posts-by-tag) they have this model, similar to your emaillist:

```
class Post(Document):
    tags = ListField(StringField(max_length=30))
```

And they query like this:

```
for post in Post.objects(tags='mongodb'):
    print post.title
```

So your query should work like this (with the case insensitivity):

```
User.Objects.filter(emaillist__iexact=email)
```